# How to handle comment flooding in a chat?

Tags: android, algorithm

I have a live stream set up in my app and there will be a chat section next to it also. It's expected to have huge amount of people who will be chatting(10000+). I want to provide a nice experience for the users so first of all I don't want comments to be unreadable because of the fast scrolling of the chat window. Secondly I want to prevent mindless spamming of certain people.

Is there any official algorithm for this?
What kind of solution is used normally?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the top of my head, I could think of the following possible solutions:

**Let users select a group**

When the users can enter a specific group with a specific 'topic' or group name the load will de distributed. However, groups might grow large

**Assign users to groups**

Create groups of let say maximum 100 users and assign people to different groups. This can either be completely random or based on some characteristics of users (like nationality).

**Set timeout for messages**

I would expect a relative small amount of people to comment intensively. This could be avoided by setting a timeout between messages, forcing them to post meaningful content in the only message they have for the next minute or two.

**Filter messages based on predefined characteristics**

This option will probably be very hard to implement. I do not know of any spam filter SDK or something like that for Android, but it might be out there. Furthermore, you would have to expect some error tolerance.